# Issues with ffmpeg image options

Tags: ffmpeg

I've some issues with combining multiple image options in ffmpeg.
My sample command with all options I want to change:

```
ffmpeg -y -i sample.jpg -qscale:v 2 -pix_fmt rgb24 -vf scale=640:480 eq=brightness=0.5:contrast=0.5:saturation=0.5 -f png output.png
```

I've several issues with this command and have been trying to rewrite it for a while, here is what I found:

1. after -vf I cannot specify both scale and eq, if I use only one it will work.
2. I cannot for some reason use -f png option.

For 1. I got such results (for both removed -f png option):

- If I have both scale and eq: 
   `[NULL @ 0000024581fd1a80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'eq=brightness=0.5:contrast=0.5:saturation=0.5' eq=brightness=0.5:contrast=0.5:saturation=0.5: Invalid argument`
- If I remove scale or eq it works

Is there any way to combine scale with options such as brightness and contrast. If I want to add another effects such as: colorchannelmixer how to add it?

Why am I getting this error with -f png option, how can I specify the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1761090/issues-with-ffmpeg-image-options), by Gyan.

1. Use "" after -vf option with elements divided by ",", eg:

   -vf "scale=640:480,eq=brightness=0.5:contrast=0.5:saturation=0.5"
2. Use -c instead of -f.